The discrepancy between the sample count in perf record and perf stat？
According to my understanding, perf stat reflects the true values of PMU events during the process's execution and can be considered as the ground truth. In contrast, perf record samples based on a specified sample_period, taking a sample when the event count exceeds the sample_period. Currently, I am using perf record -c X, where I have tested X values of 10, 100, 1000, and 10000. The results were unexpected: when X=10, the estimated event count from perf record is significantly lower than the ground truth, while for larger values of X, the estimated event count is closer to the ground truth but still shows considerable error.
What I would like to know is where the error in the estimated event count from perf record -c comes from. Taking perf record -c 1000 as an example, when the count of a certain event exceeds 1000, a sample is taken, so the final sample count should be ground_truth_count/1000. Furthermore, as -c X decreases, the sample count should increase. However, it appears that the actual sample count does not match the theoretical value.
The device I am using is a Raspberry Pi 5B, and I am running a C program for column reading of a matrix while using perf record to obtain the the number of L1D cache loads.
for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
     for (i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
          sum += matrix[i][j];
     }
}

The number of L1D cache loads obtained using perf stat is 9,205,171,526. The estimated number of L1D cache loads using perf record -c 10000 is 6,608,030,000; using perf record -c 100, the estimated count is 153,300,100; and using perf record -c 10, the estimated count is 14,859,150. I also noticed that both -c 100 and -c 10 resulted in sample counts of 1 million, while -c 10000 had a sample count of 660K. It seems that perf has limited the maximum number of sampling points.

Yes, I'd expect perf stat to be truly accurate; it is within a few counts for events like instructions on Intel CPUs at least, and highly repeatable run to run. (I'd hope ARM PMUs are similarly good.) Are you using --all-user (or -e L1-dcache-loads:u) to only count user-space?  Otherwise it's possible that different amounts of kernel code run during your test (in interrupt handlers).  I don't think that could explain 40% more counts from perf stat than the estimate from record, though.
